# Spark Java Mllib ALS algorithm training time

Tags: java, performance, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, training-data

This is a question on performance of spark mllib ALS algorithm. I'm using java to run mlib ALS algorithm on an input dataset of triplets - "userId, itemId, rating"; I am using parameter values rank=15; lambdas=0.1; numOfIteration=15; for running the ALS algorithm. The training dataset given to the algorithm is ~15M Rating triplets, consisting of 3.6M unique users and 2.26M unique items. The training took around 6 hours on one machine with 96GB resource node and 6 executors with 10G each. I saved the model and used it for predicting and evaluating a dataset of ~27M Rating triplets. The recommendProducts api took ~86 hours to complete running, which was very weird. When I ran it on a smaller dataset size, the recommendProducts api was taking more time than training - but not by a huge magnitude. The java program works and is similar to what's in scala here: http://ampcamp.berkeley.edu/4/exercises/movie-recommendation-with-mllib.html.

I'm just wondering why the program would take so long to compute als.train? And why recommendProducts would take even longer to work on a smaller dataset size. I'd be happy to give more information that might be required.

Comment: Why are you using Spark on a single machine? Spark is optimized for cluster computing - where you have many connected nodes. It wasn't made to be used on a single high performance server.

Comment: Sure, I was just testing out the program. But, my question or thought was - it should still be fast enough on a multi core machine (8) with enough memory.